# How to set image as a button in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a button and I want to set an image instead of simple text so I decided to this:

```
<ul class="signs">
    <li><button onclick="fadeOut('box1');"><img src="img/minus.png" alt="minus"/></button></li>
</ul>
```

But a little box of the button appears around the image so it's not that good. Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Just remove the button and put the onclick even on the img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's wrong with this?

```
<ul class="signs">
    <li><img src="img/minus.png" alt="minus" onclick="fadeOut('box1');"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution *(Use `background-image`)*

```css
button {
    background: red url('img/minus.png') no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="signs">
    <li><button onclick="fadeOut('box1');"></button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default styles of the button. 
 image from [here](https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&bg=ff66cc&txtclr=ffffff%26text%3Dicon1&txt=icon1&w=400&h=300)

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
button{
  border:none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul class="signs">

  <li><button onclick="fadeOut('box1');"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x70/ff66cc/ffffff&text=icon1"  alt="minus"/></button></li>
</ul>
```